# Hadoop TextOutputFormat: add headers to CSV output

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm maintaining a simple hadoop job that produces CSV files as output in the HDFS. The job uses TextOutputFormat.
I want to add the leading header row to the csv files (I know part files are created by different workers, that's not a problem if each of them gets the headers).
How to achieve this?

EDIT: Cascading can [help](http://jaysoo.ca/2012/02/10/cascading-output-csv-with-header/) but at first glance I don't want to start using a new framework

EDIT:

So I want to add headers for the output CSV files. The number of columns
are deterministic.
here is my Reducer class' skeleton:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs;

public final class Reducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
{
    private MultipleOutputs<Text, IntWritable> mos;

    private static final Text KEY_HOLDER = new Text();

    private static final IntWritable VALUE_HOLDER = new IntWritable(1);

    @Override
    public void setup(final Context context)
    {
        mos = new MultipleOutputs<Text, IntWritable>(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void cleanup(final Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        mos.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void reduce(final Text key, final Iterable<IntWritable> values, final Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        // [... some business logic ...]        
        mos.write(KEY_HOLDER, VALUE_HOLDER, "myFileName");
        context.progress();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If the question is meaningless, please tell me.

Comment: Can you add the header in your mapper or reducer? You can output the header before the real data.

Comment: Show some code please, from your description we are unable to help you on that.

Comment: @zsxwing The mapper receives a single line, the reducer receives a tuple and some numeric values... how can they operate in the context of "well this is the first line, add the headers..." ?

Comment: You can output the header in setup method.

Comment: @zsxwing Wooho, thanks, I'll take a look at it right now.

Comment: @zsxwing In the setup() method I got my MultipleOutputs instance, but the filename varies by the business logic in the reduce() method. Also, mos has only key-value write() methods. I think I'm stuck in the reduce method, because I can't know the filename outside of it.

Comment: Can you add some boolean variables to indicate if some name output has  received any data?

Comment: Yes, a boolean variable helped. Now, I have a last problem. I know when is the first invocation, but I use mos.write(Text,IntWritable,String). The last parameter tells the filename BUT as the javadoc says: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html#write%28java.lang.String,%20K,%20V,%20java.lang.String%29 " Note: Framework will generate unique filename for the baseOutputPath" Which are the part-nnnn suffixes. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can override the run() in mapper/reducer class for adding headers as per your requirement.For Ex. if you want to add FisrtName and LastName in ur final o/p.You can use the below code as a reference.

```
public void run(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {
        setup(context);
        column = new Text("ColumnName") ;
        values = new Text("FirstName" + "\t" + "LastName") ;
        context.write(column, values);
        try
        {
          while (context.nextKey())
          {
            reduce(context.getCurrentKey(), context.getValues(), context);
            Iterator<IntWritable> iter = context.getValues().iterator();
            if(iter instanceof ReduceContext.ValueIterator)
            {              ((ReduceContext.ValueIterator<IntWritable>)iter).resetBackupStore();        
            }
          }
        }
        finally
        {
          cleanup(context);
        }
  }
```